# JQuery UI Background color animate stops and goes back to original

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, background-color, jquery-ui-accordion

Ok, this one I cannot figure out.

I am working with a JQuery UI accordion, and I want to be able to change the color of one of the headers to red from a function.

I have set up an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/5sYCC/. This actually works the way I want it to run (I have it set to change the header on document ready, but that is for example only.)

It works in jsfiddle.net, but not on my local browsers. In IE and Firefox, the color change never happens and in Chrome it starts for a bit, then reverts back to the original color quickly.

I also thought of something else. I want to be able to change the background color back to it's original behavior. When it is red, I want it to stay red even when the header is selected. But I want to be able to revert back to it's original behavior of changing color upon selection. I have no idea how to go about doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is a version thing. Do you have the current version of jQuery und jQueryUI at your server?

Comment: You are sure they are loaded and working. Open the page and copy this in you browsers adresse bar to check the jQuery version: `javascript:alert(jQuery.fn.jquery)`

Comment: When I type that in, it does a Google search for it instead of displaying anything. I have switched to the Google hosted copies anyway and still get the same behavior.

Comment: ah ok, that does not work with chrome. Open the Javascript console (Strg+Shift+J) and try `jQuery.fn.jquery` there.

Comment: I get an alert that says 1.5.2. This seems incorrect. Why would I be getting that? I had 1.4.? on the machine for a while, but I never developed on it. And I replaced it with 1.6.4, and have even removed all references to the local copy on the pages to the google version.

Comment: Can't tell from here... See that the script is loaded: (Strg+Shift+J) => Network, reload page.

Comment: Ok. I changed the references back to the local copies and now I get 1.6.4 on the alert. But it still does not work. It starts to change red, then reverts back. [I uploaded the change.](http://www.gtacswim.info/tools/Tests/JQueryUI.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code for changing the color to something else: http://jsfiddle.net/5sYCC/1/ . And about the js not working; I think PiTheNumber is right here. Check your path to the scripts aswell.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I now have it figured out how to go back to the original settings. I will just have to basically reprogram it back to default behavior. Paths to the scripts are correct or it wouldn't even look like that in the first place. It would just be regular <h3> tags.

Comment: I just switched to the google hosted copies of the most recent versions of JQuery and JQuery UI, and I get the same behavior. (In fact Chrome defaults back to original color even faster now.) I applied your settings on the local copy, and Section 2 never changes to green locally.

Comment: Tested in Chrome here, works like it should, both setting color and changing it back. There must be something wrong on your end.

Comment: I don't understand how though. I am not even referencing local copies.

Comment: Is your file big? Mind copying it up to pastebin.com or something?

Comment: The stuff posted at [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5sYCC/1/) is the entire file because it is just a test at this point. I have not created the actual page I want to do yet. I will post at pastebin in a moment.

Comment: OK. Posted: http://pastebin.com/PBfzSin9. The entire CSS file is here: http://jsfiddle.net/5sYCC/1/ under the "CSS" pane.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/tQtem/ - It works. Only missing the css that you can include yourself.

Comment: Yes, it has worked in jsfiddle since the start, but it won't work locally. Here is the exact file. I have edited the pastebin file: http://pastebin.com/PBfzSin9 so that it imports the stylesheet from my server and all the javascript from Google, so there should be no linking issues. It works fine in jsfiddle, but it doesn't work on my computer.

Comment: When I copy paste your code in on my end, it still doesn't work.

Comment: [Does this work for you the way it does on Jfiddle?](http://www.gtacswim.info/tools/Tests/JQueryUI.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that the animation of Section 2 should only be attempted at the event handler of an event that indicates the start of the accordion change like "changeStar

Comment: I only put it in the document ready as a test. I have not actually created the page I want to use the functionally in yet because I wanted to make sure I could do it first. The server is going to post a form inside each panel, and the javascript will change the color of the panel on the ones that need to be addressed. Then, when they are fixed, they will revert to regular functionality.